# Как просуммировать списки разных размеров?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список

```
def suma(x,y):
    i = 0
    z=[]
    while i< len(x)<len(y):
        z.append(x[i]+y[i])
        i+=1
    return z

print(suma([1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]))
```

Comment: а чт должно получиться?

Comment: @MaxU я предполагаю, [2,4,6] :)

Comment: `return [a+b for a,b in zip(x,y)]`

Comment: должно получится [2,4,6,4] )

Answer (score 3):

воспользуйтесь функцией [itertools.zip_longest()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest):

```
from itertools import zip_longest

res = [a+b for a,b in zip_longest(x, y, fillvalue=0)]
```

---

результат:

```
In [58]: res
Out[58]: [2, 4, 6, 4]
```